# How to make 50000-digit variable

Tags: c

I need variable that I'm getting from user and it's digit range is 1<=n<=50000. Is it possible to solve this problem in c?

I just want to get two numbers from user, n - as x number and n - digit y number. I will just make x*x on x, and I won't increase y (only divide it).

EDIT:
The problem is:
For example I'm getting two numbers: 5 and 90625. I need to check if 90625 is automorphic. But I can get numbers to 50000 as first parameter, for example 49555 and 38459654365...(49555 digits). How can I work on it?

Comment: C is turing complete so yes, it's possible. ;-)

Comment: any tip how can I solve this? :)

Comment: I suggest you ask that question by editing your original post!

Comment: For further clarification (btw -- you still ask whether it's possible!): You say "get from user". I guess they are not typing 50000 digits. What format does the number have? Ascii? And how is it generated?

Comment: I need to pass it through checker so probably it will try use variable with about 50000 digits.

Comment: better to use `linked list` and store each `digit` as node `value`. since memory allocation will be dynamic so any no of digit it can have.

Answer (score 6):

If you are performing any maths operations then you probably want something like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) which allows you to have arbitrary size integers.

Comment: I just want to get two numbers from user, n - as x number and n - digit y number. I will just make n*n on x, and I won't increase y (only divide it).

Comment: yeah in that case you probably want to use GMP. IIRC you can instantiate numbers using a string of digits, so just read the 50 digit number into a string and pass it to a GMP integer.

Comment: Well, as HelloWorld says, the only limitation GMP has in terms of the size of the numbers it can store is the memory available on the machine, assuming you have a reasonably modern machine, you should be able to easily store and multiply digits with pretty large values of k. How much depends on how much memory you have.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have arbitary size integers. Try with [GMP - lib](https://gmplib.org/)

`GMP` is a free library for **arbitrary precision arithmetic**, **operating on signed integers**, **rational numbers**, and **floating-point numbers**. There is no practical limit to the precision except the ones implied by the available memory in the machine GMP runs on. GMP has a rich set of functions, and the functions have a regular interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can save it in a C array, each element for each digit.

Comment: hm, I want make scanf from user, can I pass it straight to array instead of variable?

Comment: @user3852834: `scanf("%s", buf)` !??

Comment: You can read digit by digit. Each time you get a digit, you store it in the array and make the subscript of the array increase by 1.

Comment: @Linjie You can also do it in assembler. Use the keyboard interrupt. Watch for bouncing keys though.

Answer (score -1):

Use data type long, its range is –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647